# Conditional state based on the route

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a Vuex state property that stores a boolean that I use to determine whether to show or hide the nav bar.  For all pages except the landing page the nav bar should appear so I set the default value to true.

```
export const state = () => ({
    showNav: true
})
```

Then I have a mutation for toggling that.

```
export const mutations = {
    toggleNav (state, show) {
        state.showNav = show
    }
}
```

In my landing page, I have a call to `toggleNav` to turn off the nav bar.

```
export default {
    mounted () {
        this.$store.commit('toggleNav', false)
    }
}
```

This works as expected with one big problem; When I refresh the landing page I see the nav bar for a brief second until mounted() gets called.

Is there some way to hide the nav bar such that it doesn't briefly appear?  I realized I could default `showNav` to `false` and then call `this.$store.commit('toggleNav', true)` on every page but that seems unwieldy.

EDIT: The nav bar is itself its own component.

EDIT 2: I forgot to add that I need to be able to dynamically show the nav bar when `scrollY` exceeds a certain value and then hide it again when `scrollY` returns below that value. My apologies to everyone who answered for not being clearer about this.

Comment: Try using the `created` hook since it is earlier in the lifecycle...or perhaps a re-purposed [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) if you're using vue-router (make the commit within the `beforeRouteEnter` guard).

Comment: @zer0kompression Neither of those work.  I think these still happen too late in the lifecycle.

Comment: How about using `v-if` on the navbar component based on the current route? So something like `<navbar v-if="$route.path !== '/landing-page-path'"/>`.

Comment: @zer0kompression See my second edit.  I actually did have `v-if="$route.path !== '/landing-page-path'"` at one point but I couldn't get the nav bar to dynamically appear again after the page had loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nuxt, middlewares attached to a layout or a page are run [on load and on every route change](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware).

So the most straightforward way is to use a middleware to check for current path and toggle your nav:

```
/* store/index.js */
export const store = () => ({
  showNav: true
});

export const mutations = {
  toggleNav(state, bool){
    state.showNav = bool;
  }
}


/* middleware/toggleNavMiddleware.js */
export default function(context){
  const { route, store } = context;
  store.commit('toggleNav', route.path === /* your landing page path */);
}


/* layouts/default.vue (assuming this is the target) */
/* you can also use it in pages/*.vue */
export default {
  middleware: ['toggleNavMiddleware'],
}


/* components/NavBar.vue */
<template>
  <nav v-if="$store.state.showNav">
    <!-- content here -->
  </nav>
</template>
```

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon I have tested it myself and it works just fine. So please show/explain more of your code or let me know how you implemented it instead?.

Comment: `export default function` has a syntax error (unnecessary trailing parenthesis) and, correct me if I'm wrong but `$store.state.showNav` should reference `toggleNav` instead of `showNav`, no?  I should clarify that if I fix those problems then the nav bar does disappear but (and this is my fault for not being clear in my question) I'm unable to dynamically get the nav bar to appear after the page has loaded.  I need to, in effect, call `store.commit('toggleNav', true)` when the user scrolls to the top of the page and have the nav appear again.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Corrected the trailing parenthesis. Based on your snippet, it should reference `$store.state.showNav` because that's what is exposed in `state = () => ({ showNav: true })`. `toggleNav` is in mutations so it shouldn't be reference and can only be committed. Can you update your question to make it clearer? To clarify, nav bar should disappear on load, but reappear again should the user scrolls to the top, correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying.  After implementing that it does work as expected.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on state mutation, this had probably best be done during design-time by including a [`meta`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields) field when defining the routes. Something like `meta.showNavBar`. For example:

#### routes.js

```js
export default [
  {
    // The landing page
    path: '/welcome',
    name: 'Welcome',
    meta: {
      showNavbar: false
    },
    component: () => import('@/views/Welcome')
  },

  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Homepage',
    meta: {
      // Don't worry about this since we'll take care of it with a computed property.
      // showNavbar: true
    },
    component: () => import('@/views/Home')
  },

  {
    // ...
  }
]
```

#### SomeComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <navbar v-if="showNavbar"></navbar>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      showNavbar() {
        const { showNavbar } = this.$route.meta;

        return showNavbar || typeof showNavbar === 'undefined';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could call it `meta.hideNavbar`, set it to `true` for the landing page and coerce its value to boolean with double-negation operator (`!!`) -- which will default to `false` when not set or left `undefined`, from here, you could simply do:

```
<navbar v-if="!!$route.meta.hideNavbar"></navbar>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I'm guessing because I'm using NuxtJS instead of pure Vue?

Comment: The basic idea can be implemented with a middleware component (Nuxt)

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Not quite sure about how it is different from the NuxtJs version, but yes this minimal setup usually suffices for me. I'm not working with NuxtJs myself, so. Glad you found the answer though.